# Partition & consecutive in SQL

Tags: sql, window-functions

fellow stackers

I have a data set like so:

```
+---------+------+--------+
| user_id | date | metric |
+---------+------+--------+
|       1 |    1 |      1 |
|       1 |    2 |      1 |
|       1 |    3 |      1 |
|       2 |    1 |      1 |
|       2 |    2 |      1 |
|       2 |    3 |      0 |
|       2 |    4 |      1 |
+---------+------+--------+
```

I am looking to flag those customers who has 3 consecutive "1"s in the metric column. I have a solution as below.

```
select      distinct user_id
from        (
             select      user_id
                         ,metric +
                          ifnull( lag(metric, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date), 0 ) +
                          ifnull( lag(metric, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date), 0 )
                          as consecutive_3
             from        df
             ) b
where       consecutive_3 = 3
```

While it works it is not scalable. As one can imagine what the above query would look like if I were looking for a consecutive 50.
May I ask if there is a scalable solution? Any cloud SQL will do. Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want such users, you can use a `sum()`.  Assuming that `metric` is only `0` or `1`:

```
select user_id,
       (case when max(metric_3) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as flag_3
from (select df.*,
             sum(metric) over (partition by user_id
                               order by date
                               rows between 2 preceding and current row
                              ) as metric_3
      from df
     ) df
group by user_id;
```

By using a windowing clause, you can easily expand to as many adjacent `1`s as you like.

Comment: rows between 2 preceding and current row
This did the trick. It was what I was looking for.  I was aware of "rows unbounded preceding" but not an actual number as a boundary. Thank you, Gordon